# A proposition on a Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra

I need a proof of the following proposition(?).
Actually I think I came up with a proof.
But it's nice to confirm it and/or to know other proofs.
Thanks.

**Proposition**
Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain.
Let $I$ and $J$ be non-zero ideals of $A$.
Then there exist non-zero $\alpha \in I$ and an ideal $M$ such that $(\alpha) = IM, M + J = A$.

**EDIT**
Here's my proof.
Let $I = (P_1)^{e_1}...(P_n)^{e_n}$ be the prime decomposition of I.
Let $Q_1, ..., Q_m$ be all the prime ideals which divide $J$, but not divide $I$.
By the [proposition](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156744/existence-of-an-element-of-given-orders-at-finitely-many-prime-ideals-of-a-dedek) and with its notation, there exists $\alpha \in A$ such that
$v_{P_i}(\alpha) = e_i, i = 1, ..., n$.
$v_{Q_j}(\alpha) = 0, j = 1, ..., m$.
Since $\alpha \in I$, there exists an ideal $M$ such that $(\alpha) = IM$.
Clearly $M + J = A$

Comment: Since $M$ is completely determined by $I$ and $\alpha$, perhaps you might want to state the result only in terms of $\alpha$: there is a nonzero $\alpha \in A$ such that $(\alpha) + IJ = I$, or equivalently ${\rm gcd}((\alpha),IJ) = I$. (An $\alpha$ satisfying this equation is automatically in $I$.) Does your proof use the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: There's probably a pithy way of stating this in terms of the class group, right?

Comment: @KCd Yes, it does.

Comment: The proof I'm thinking of uses the CRT as well. I can reproduce it below, but it seems likely that it's identical to yours.

Comment: @Dylan I'd like to know your proof.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are right. The essential point is the weak approximation theorem which you cite as the proposition. The weak approximation theorem is in turn essentially Chinese remainder theorem.