# Existence of an element of given orders at finitely many prime ideals of a Dedekind domain

Tags: commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain.
Let $P$ be a non-zero prime ideal of $A$.
Let $\alpha \in A$.
Let $k$ be a non-negative integer.
If $\alpha \in P^k$ and $\alpha\notin P^{k+1}$, we write $v_P(\alpha) = k$.

How can we prove the following

**Proposition.**
Let $A$ be a Dedekind domain.
Let $P_1,\dots, P_n$ be distinct non-zero prime ideals of $A$.
Let $e_1, \dots, e_n$ be non-negative integers.
Then there exists $\alpha \in A$ such that $v_{P_i}(\alpha) = e_i$, $i = 1,\dots, n$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the [Approximation Theorem?](http://planetmath.org/WeakApproximationTheorem.html)

Comment: I know one form of approximation theorem(as stated in Serre's Local fields), but I didn't know that in the link. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each $i$ choose $\alpha_i\in\ P_i^{e_i}\setminus P_i^{e_i+1}$. Then $v_{P_i}(\alpha_i)=e_i$ for $i=1,\ldots,n$. The ideals $P_1^{e_1+1},\ldots,P_n^{e_n+1}$ are pairwise relatively prime, so the Chinese remainder theorem implies there is $\alpha\in A$ with $\alpha\equiv\alpha_i\pmod{P_i^{e_i+1}}$ for all $i$. Then $\alpha$ has the desired property.