# Representation of an algebraic number as a fraction of algebraic integers which are relatively prime to a given ideal

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a finite extension of the field of rational numbers.
Let $A$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $A$.
Let $\alpha$ be a non-zero element of $K$ which is relatively prime to $I$.

Are there algebraic integers $\beta$, $\gamma$ in $A$ with the following properties?

(1) $\alpha = \beta/\gamma$.

(2) $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are relatively prime to $I$.

**EDIT(Mar.2,2013)**
Here is [a generalization of this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318250/representation-of-an-element-of-the-field-of-fractions-of-a-dedekind-domain-as-a).

Comment: I wonder was this question downvoted because it's a poor question? Or because Makoto is the one asking it?

Comment: PS I interpreted "relatively prime to $I$" to mean "the prime factorizations of the invertible ideals $(\alpha)$ and $I$ don't have any primes in common".

Comment: Can the assertion be proved without using the fact that the class number of $K$ is finite?

Comment: @Hurkyl I didn't think it's necessary to define a self-evident terminology.

Comment: The other self-evident meaning is $1 \notin I + (\alpha)$. A priori, this doesn't look equivalent to the other when $\alpha$ is an element of the fraction field.

Comment: ... and there are other directions it could be interpreted. Overall, I decided it was worth making an explicit clarification (someplace out of the way of the main train of thought) so that the reader isn't forced to guess.

Comment: @Hurkyl That doesn't make sense. Lang uses the same terminology as mine by the way.

Comment: @Hurkyl So that's why you downvoted?

Comment: I hope someone would prove the assertion without using the fact that the class number of $K$ is finite. Then the proof might be applied to any Dedekind domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any "obvious" algorithm works. Many/most of them could even be adapted to a proof.

The following is a quick proof that there isn't an obstacle to avoiding $I$:

Factor $(\alpha)$ as $J_1 / J_2$ where $J_i$ are integral ideals both relatively prime to $I$ (e.g. by splitting the factorization of $(\alpha)$ into the parts with positive and negative exponent).

Let $J_2^h = (g)$ for some positive integer $h$ (e.g. let $h$ be the class number of $K$).

Then we can choose $\beta = g \alpha$ and $\gamma = g$.

Comment: Your proof is valid, but I prefer a proof using http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154042/a-proposition-on-a-dedekind-domain.
See the YACP's answer to the following question:
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/318250/representation-of-an-element-of-the-field-of-fractions-of-a-dedekind-domain-as-a