# Decomposition of a primitive ideal of a quadratic order

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, alternative-proof

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $\mathcal{O}_K$ be the ring of algebraic integers in $K$.
Let $R$ be an order of $K$, $D$ its discriminant.
I am interested in the ideal theory on $R$ because it has a deep connection with the theory of binary quadratic forms as shown in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic). 
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546281/on-a-certain-basis-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $1, \omega = \frac{(D + \sqrt D)}{2}$ is a basis of $R$ as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be a sequence of elements of $R$.
We denote by $[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$ generated by $x_1,\cdots, x_n$.

Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $R$.
I am interested in a decomposition of $I$ into a product of ideals.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552516/canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order), there exist unique rational integers $a, b, c$ such that $I = [a, b + c\omega], a \gt 0, c \gt 0, 0 \le b \lt a, a \equiv 0$ (mod $c$), $b \equiv 0$ (mod $c$).
If $c = 1$, we say $I$ is a primitive ideal.
Let $a = ca'$, $b = cb'$.
Then $I = cJ$, where $J = [a', b' + \omega]$.
Clearly $J$ is a primitive ideal.
So the decomposition problem can be reduced to the case when $I$ is primitive.

Let $\frak{f}$ $= \{x \in R | x\mathcal{O}_K \subset R\}$.
Let $I$ be a non-zero ideal of $R$.
If $I + \mathfrak{f} = R$, we call $I$ regular.
For the properties of regular ideals, see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain).
We call a non-zero ideal $J$ totally non-regular if every prime ideal containing $J$ is non-regular.
I came up with the following proposition.

**Proposition**
Let $I = [a, r + \omega]$ be a primitive ideal of $R$, where $a \gt 0$ and $r$ are rational integers. Then $I$ can be uniquely decomposed into $I = JM$, where $J$ is a regular ideal and $M$ is a totally non-regular ideal.
Moreover there exist rational integers $g \gt 0, h \gt 0$ such that $a = gh$ and
$J = [g, r + \omega], M = [h, r + \omega]$.

**Outline of my proof**
I used the results of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557548/on-the-norm-formula-nij-ninj-in-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field) and mimicked my proof of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556288/decomposition-of-a-primitive-regular-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order).

**My Question**
How do you prove the proposition?
I would like to know other proofs based on different ideas from mine.
I welcome you to provide as many different proofs as possible.
I wish the proofs would be detailed enough for people who have basic knowledge of introductory algebraic number theory to be able to understand.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that there exist unique positive rational integers $g, h$ such that $a = gh$ and gcd$(g, f) = 1$ and every prime divisor of $h$ is a prime divisor of $f$.

Let $\sigma$ be the unique non-identity automorphism of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
Since $\omega + \sigma(\omega) = D$, $\sigma(\omega) \in R$.
Hence $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(r + \omega) = (r + \omega)(r + \sigma(\omega)) \in I$.
Since $N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(r + \omega) \in \mathbb{Z}$, it is divisible by $a$.
Hence it is divisible by $g$ and $h$.
Hence by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/553942/condition-for-a-b-omega-to-be-the-canonical-basis-of-an-ideal-of-a-quadrat), $J = [g, r + \omega]$ and $M = [h, r + \omega]$ are ideals of $R$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556643/criterion-on-whether-a-given-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order-is-regular-or-not), $J$ is regular.
We claim that $M$ is totally non-regular.
Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$ containing $M$.
It suffices to prove that $P$ is not regular.
Let $p$ be the unique prime number contained in $P$.
Since $h \in P$, $h$ is divisible by $p$.
Since $f$ is divisible by $p$, $f \in P$.
Hence $P$ is not regular by Lemma 4 of my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/556643/criterion-on-whether-a-given-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order-is-regular-or-not).

Next we prove that $I = JM$.
Let $\theta = r + \omega$.
Then $JM = (g, \theta)(h, \theta) = (gh, g\theta, h\theta, \theta^2) \subset I$.
It is easy to see that $N(I) = a$.
Similarly $N(J) = g, N(M) = h$.
Hence $N(I) = N(J)N(M)$.
Since $J$ is regular, $N(J)N(M) = N(JM)$ by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557548/on-the-norm-formula-nij-ninj-in-an-order-of-an-algebraic-number-field).
Hence $I = JM$.

It remains to prove the uniqueness of the decomposition $I = JM$.
Note that, by [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/158876/ideal-class-group-of-a-one-dimensional-noetherian-domain), $J$ is invertible and uniquely decomposed as a product of regular prime ideals.
Let $I = J'M'$ be another such decomposition.
Since $J$ is invertible, it suffices to prove that $J = J'$.
Suppose $J \subset P^e$, $e \ge 1$ where $P$ is a prime ideal.
It suffices to prove that $J' \subset P^e$.
Since $J \subset P$ and $J$ is regular, $P$ is also regular.
Hence $P$ does not contain $M'$.
Hence $M' + P^e = R$.
Hence there exist $\mu \in M'$ and $\pi \in P^e$ such that $\mu + \pi = 1$.
Let $x \in J'$.
Since $x = \mu x + \pi x$ and $M'J' \subset P^e$, $x \in P^e$.
Hence $J' \subset P^e$ as desired.