# On equivalence of primitive ideals of an order of a quadratic number field

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $R$ be an order of $K$, i.e. a subring of $K$ which is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of rank $2$.
Let $D$ be the discriminant of $R$.
Let $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ be a sequence of elements of $R$.
We denote by $[x_1,\cdots,x_n]$ the $\mathbb{Z}$-submodule of $R$ generated by $x_1,\cdots, x_n$.
By [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546281/on-a-certain-basis-of-an-order-of-a-quadratic-number-field), $R = [1, \omega]$, where $\omega = (D + \sqrt D)/2$.
Let us consider the following problem.

**Problem**
Let $I, J$ be non-zero ideals of $R$.
Under what condition does there exist $\alpha \in K$ such that $I = \alpha J$?

This problem is clearly important in computing the ideal class group of $R$(see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/192217/bijection-between-an-ideal-class-group-and-a-set-of-classes-of-binary-quadratic) for the definition of the ideal class group of $R$). Clearly we can assume that $I$ and $J$ are primitive ideals(see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/557659/decomposition-of-a-primitive-ideal-of-a-quadratic-order) for the definition of a primitive ideal).

**My question**
Is the following proposition correct?
If yes, how do you prove it?

**Proposition**
Let $I = [a, k + \omega], J = [b, l + \omega]$ be primitive ideals of $R$, where $a,k, b, l \in \mathbb{Z}, a \gt 0, b \gt 0$.
Let $\theta = (k + \omega)/a, \tau = (l + \omega)/b$.
Then there exists $\alpha \in K$ such that $I = \alpha J$ if and only if there exist integers $p, q, r, s$, such that $ps - qr = \pm 1$ and $\theta = (p\tau + q)/(r\tau + s)$.
Moreover, if we require an additional condition $N(\alpha) \gt 0$, then we must replace $ps - qr = \pm 1$ by $ps - qr = 1$.
Note that when $D \lt 0$, this condition is automatically satisfied, i.e. $N(\alpha) \gt 0$ for all non-zero $\alpha \in K$.

Comment: If there is something wrong with this question someone must say it.

Answer (score 0):

**Notation**
Let $K$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $\sigma$ be the unique non-identity automorphism of $K/\mathbb{Q}$.
Let $\alpha \in K$.
We denote $\sigma(\alpha)$ by $\alpha'$.

Let $\alpha, \beta \in K$.
We denote the determinant of the matrix $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \alpha' \\
\beta & \beta' \end{array} \right)$ by $\Delta(\alpha, \beta)$.
Namely $\Delta(\alpha, \beta) = \alpha\beta' - \alpha'\beta$.

**Lemma 1**
Let $K$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $I$ be a free $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules of $K$ of rank $2$.
Let $\mu, \nu$ be its basis over $\mathbb{Z}$.
Let $\alpha, \beta \in I$.
There exist $p, q, r, s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\alpha = p\mu + q\nu, \beta = r\mu + s\nu$.
Then $\Delta(\alpha, \beta) = (ps - qr)\Delta(\mu, \nu)$.

Proof:
This follows immediately from the following equation.

$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \alpha' \\
\beta & \beta' \end{array} \right)$ =
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
p & q \\
r & s \end{array} \right)$
$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\mu & \mu' \\
\nu & \nu' \end{array} \right)$.

**Lemma 2**
Let $K$ be a quadratic number field.
Let $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in I$.
Then $\Delta(\gamma\alpha, \gamma\beta) = N(\gamma)\Delta(\alpha, \beta)$.

Proof:
$\Delta(\gamma\alpha, \gamma\beta) = \gamma\alpha\gamma'\beta' - \gamma'\alpha'\gamma\beta = \gamma\gamma'(\alpha\beta' - \alpha'\beta) = N(\gamma)\Delta(\alpha, \beta)$.

**Proof of the proposition**

Suppose there exists $\alpha \in K$ such that $I = \alpha J$.
Then $[a, k + \omega] = \alpha[b, l + \omega] = [\alpha b, \alpha (l + \omega)]$.
Hence there exist $p, q, r, s \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $ps - qr = \pm 1$ and

$k + \omega = p\alpha (l + \omega) + q\alpha b = \alpha(p(l + \omega) + qb)$,

$a = r\alpha (l + \omega) + s\alpha b = \alpha(r(l + \omega) + sb)$.

Hence $\theta = (p(l + \omega) + qb)/(r(l + \omega) + sb) = (p\tau + q)/(r\tau + s)$.

Suppose $N(\alpha) \gt 0$.
Let $P = ps - qr$.
By Lemma 1 and Lemma 2, $\Delta(a, k + \omega) = P\Delta(\alpha b, \alpha (l + \omega)) =
PN(\alpha)\Delta(b, l + \omega)$.
Since $\Delta(a, k + \omega) = -a\sqrt D, \Delta(b, l + \omega) = -b\sqrt D$,
$a = PN(\alpha)b$.
Hence $P$ must be positive, i.e. $P = 1$.

Conversely suppose $\theta = (p\tau + q)/(r\tau + s)$, where $p, q, r, s \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $ps - qr = \pm 1$.
Let $\alpha = a/(b(r\tau + s))$.
Then $a = \alpha b(r\tau + s)$.
$a\theta = \alpha b(r\tau + s)\theta = \alpha b(p\tau + q)$.
Hence $[a, a\theta] = [\alpha b(r\tau + s), \alpha b(p\tau + q)] = \alpha b[r\tau + s, p\tau + q] = \alpha b[1, \tau] = \alpha [b, b\tau]$.
Hence $I = \alpha J$.

Let $P = ps - qr$.
By the same argument as above, $a = PN(\alpha)b$.
Hence, if $P = 1$, $N(\alpha) \gt 0$.
**QED**